# Save Cookies inside TIDCookieManager to file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10, delphi-xe3

How can I save cookies inside `TIdCookieManager` to a file so that they can be used later? Like browser cookies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TIdCookieManager` does not have any native support for persisting cookie data in files.  You have to implement that manually.  Use the `TIdCookieManager.CookieCollection` property to access the list of cookie objects.  For example:

```
uses
  ..., IdCookie, IdCookieManager;

var
  Cookies: TIdCookieList;
  Cookie: TIdCookie;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Cookies := IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.LockCookieList(caRead);
  try
    for I := 0 to Cookies.Count-1 do
    begin
      Cookie := Cookies[I];
      // save Cookie properties as needed...
    end;
  finally
    IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.UnlockCookieList(caRead);
  end;
end;
```

.

```
uses
  ..., IdCookie, IdCookieManager;

var
  Cookies: TIdCookies;
  Cookie: TIdCookie;
begin
  Cookies := IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.LockCookieList(caReadWrite);
  try
    for (each saved cookie) do
    begin
      Cookie := IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.Add;
      try
        // read Cookie properties as needed...
        Cookies.Add(Cookie);
      except
        Cookie.Free;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.UnlockCookieList(caReadWrite);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
uses
  ..., IdCookie, IdCookieManager;

var
  Cookies: TIdCookieList;
  Cookie: TIdCookie;
  I: Integer;
  S: string;
begin
  Cookies := IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.LockCookieList(caRead);
  try
    for I := 0 to Cookies.Count-1 do
    begin
      Cookie := Cookies[I];
      S := Cookie.ServerCookie;
      // save S as needed...
    end;
  finally
    IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.UnlockCookieList(caRead);
  end;
end;
```

.

```
uses
  ..., IdCookie, IdCookieManager, IdURI;

var
  S: string;
  Cookies: TIdCookies;
  Cookie: TIdCookie;
  Uri: TIdURI;
begin
  Cookies := IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.LockCookieList(caReadWrite);
  try
    for (each saved cookie) do
    begin
      // read S as needed
      S := ...;
      Uri := TIdURI.Create(URL where cookie came from);
      try
        Cookie := IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.Add;
        try
          Cookie.ParseServerCookie(S, Uri);
          Cookies.Add(Cookie);
        except
          Cookie.Free;
          raise;
        end;
    finally
      Uri.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdCookieManager.CookieCollection.UnlockCookieList(caReadWrite);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this DOES answer the question. I should know, considering that I helped write `TIdCookie` and `TIdCookieManager` to begin with. You have to loop through the `TIdCookieManager.CookieCollection` manually, writing out the individual cookies to file yourself, and then reading them back yourself, exactly as I showed. Why do you say this does not answer the question? Because I did not include any file I/O code? I left that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: As for `TIdCookie` itself, it is a valid class type in recent versions. If your version does not recognize it, then you must be using an outdated version that was still based on old `TIdNetscapeCookie`, `TIdCookieRFC2109`, and `TIdCookieRFC2965` classes that no longer exist, replaced with `TIdCookie` when Indy implemented RFC 6265.

Comment: They are declared in `IdCookie.pas`. If you look at the actual `TIdCookie` class, it has individual properties that you can read/write to file one at a time as needed, or you can use the `TIdCookie.ServerCookie` property and `TIdCookie.ParseServerCookie` method. I don't think its fair to unaccept a correct answer when I did say you would have to read/write the cookie values manually.

Comment: Although I did not unaccept the answer, I do apologize for the last few comments. +1 for the answer! Works like a charm now :)