# How to copy cookies in Indy 10

Tags: delphi, indy, cookiemanager

I'm using Indy 10 in Delphi 7.
I have a TidCookieManager in a main form and I wish to copy its cookies over to another cookie manager in a separate thread, this thread obviously has access to the main form.

How do I copy those cookies?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Start by taking a look at TIdCookieManager's CookieCollection and CopyCookie(). Run the code in a synchronize block. Take a look at the answer to:  [Save Cookies inside TIDCookieManager to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382732/save-cookies-inside-tidcookiemanager-to-file) for some help with interating through cookies.

Comment: "*Run the code in a synchronize block*" - that is not necessary since the `CookieCollection` uses a thread lock (specifically, a `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`). Locking the source and destination `CookieCollection`s while iterating+copying will provide adequate synchronization. Also, you don't need to iterate+copy the individual cookies manually as the `CookieCollection` has `Assign()` and `AddCookies()` methods to handle that operation for you.

Answer (score 3):

`TIdCookieManager` has a public `CookieCollection` property of type `TIdCookies` which provides access to the actual cookies.  The cookies of one `TIdCookies` can be directly copied to another `TIdCookies` via its `Assign()` or `AddCookies()` method, eg:

```pascal
// clears the dest collection before then copying cookies to it...
CookieMgrInWorkerThread.CookieCollection.Assign(CookieMgrInMainThread.CookieCollection);
```

```pascal
// does not clear the dest collection before copying cookies to it...
CookieMgrInWorkerThread.CookieCollection.AddCookies(CookieMgrInMainThread.CookieCollection);
```

Either way, `TIdCookies` is thread-safe, as it uses an internal `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` during read/write operations.